# 405 Error & CORS when making an api request on localhost

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to pull data from a weather API on my localhost environment and I'm getting a 405 Error(Method not allowed) as well as "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status." I've config'd my headers and can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. It works fine on live but obviously that's not a convenient way doing it.

I've tried using axios.get as well as axios.post.

```js
var config = {
    headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
};
getWeather: function (){
    axios.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id='+ city + '&appid='+ apiKey, config).then((res) => {this.weather = res.data});
}
```

Comment: can you show the error message?

Comment: I think chrome blocks it by default. Try other browser maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Hope adding below package will help

```
use this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

**Installation :**

`composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors`

**Service provider :**

Add this `Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,` in `config/app.php`

To allow `CORS` **for all your routes**, add the `HandleCors` middleware in the `$middleware` property of `app/Http/Kernel.php` class:

```
protected $middleware = [
 \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
 // ...
];
```

**NOTE: make sure to place it before all middlewares**

If it's for specific middleware, on our case, it will be `api`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
'web' => [
   // ...
],

'api' => [
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class, 
    'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
],
```

];

**NOTE: make sure to place it before all middlewares**

Publish the config :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"
```